# Shortening class names/global variables in Sencha Touch

Tags: class, sencha-touch, global-variables

According to best practices (for instance, http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to-avoid), I should avoid using global variables and instead create them as configs of a static class, ApplicationName.foldername.Classname.

Hence, a call to a tiny variable *varName* would become a verbose *ApplicationName.foldername.Classname.getVarName()*.

Is is possible to shorten the *ApplicationName.foldername.Classname* part, in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all just JavaScript - so technically `ApplicationName.foldername.Classname` **is** a global variable, albeit one that is unlikely to create naming collisions in this use case.

In other words, the likelihood that something short like `varName` is used more than once in a large application is pretty high... which is why it's bad practice. Creating something shorter, while certainly more convenient (less typing), is riskier.

Comment: THIS is the answer! thank you for having dug to the roots of the question.